# Print Software for Monoprice Dual Extruder

Tags: software, monoprice-dual-extrusion

Back in 2015 I bought the [Monoprice Dual Extruder 3D printer](https://www.cnet.com/reviews/monoprice-dual-extrusion-3d-printer-review/) (I know it was a clone of a FlashForge or a Makerbot, but I don't remember which).

I played with it for a while but we moved and I never got back to it... Until now.

It still had the SD card in it with my last attempt at 3D modeling, and it printed perfectly on the first attempt. So the printer is fine after a couple years in a box.

I use SketchUp Pro and have installed the STL export add-on.

I have the following questions:

- What is the latest Software I should be using?
- Is there (more) current firmware I should update to?

Comment: That are two questions: one about a slicer, and the accompaning settings, one about the firmware. You should split it... oh, and welcome to the stack!